# Opposite of "well understood"

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

I wanted to say about a field in physics, that

> the laws are **not well understood**.

To my ear, "well understood" sounds fine, but "not well" sounds clumsy, and  any antonym I tried seems a little wrong...

How would I call it:

- badly?
- or ill?
- or poorly?
- or [...]

Comment: ["Not well understood" is a perfectly valid, common phrase.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=not+well+understood#tbm=bks&q=%22not+well+understood%22)  I don't see any problem with using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather common expression in the sciences is *little understood*.

Here are several examples from scientific literature:

> Yet these same organisms happen to be, in the language favored by field biologists, “vastly undersampled.” Consequently, they have been little studied and so are **little understood**.<sup>1</sup>
>
> Although these physiological diseases are **little understood**, it is known that they are all communicable and hereditary.<sup>2</sup>
>
> The rigor of formal simulation models seems especially important where the processes are **little understood** and the task environments loosely structured.<sup>3</sup>
>
> The principles by which hypotheses are discovered, or invented, are **little understood**, but the testing of hypotheses is a more tractable matter.<sup>4</sup>
>
> The electromagnetic properties of charged particles were **little understood** until the British mathematician and physicist Michael Faraday discovered the laws of electromagnetic induction in 1831.<sup>5</sup>
>
> However, from a physical standpoint, entanglement is **little understood**. The questions of what exactly it is and how it works are still not resolved.<sup>6</sup>
>
> Therapeutic vaccines are **little understood**<sup>7</sup>

---

<sub>S O U R C E S</sub>

<sup>1</sup>*Weird Life: The Search for Life That Is Very, Very Different from Our Own* by David Toomey, 2013.
<sup>2</sup>From a report on a 1912 International Convention on Horticulture.
<sup>3</sup>*Cognition and Instruction* By David Klahr, 2014.
<sup>4</sup>*Psychology of Reasoning: Structure and Content* by P. C. Wason and P. N. Johnson-Laird, 1972.
<sup>5</sup>*The Truth About Tesla* by Christopher Cooper, 2015.
<sup>6</sup>*Quantum Backpropagation Neural Network Approach for Modeling of Phenol Adsorption from Aqueous Solution by Orange Peel Ash* by Bhattacharjeem, Bhattacharyya and Mondal, 2014.
<sup>7</sup>Headline from *The Telegraph*, Sep 11, 1994 (page 64).

Comment: ah, this is obviuosly exactly what I was looking for; it seems to be rather science-specific, since the others didn't associate it?

Comment: ...and maybe it's a rather new expression (at least your first reference from 1972)?

Comment: @Ilja - Perhaps you missed the reference from 1912? The phase goes  even earlier than that, actually: _One would imagine, that if little of real use can be said concerning madness, it must be little understood_ (G.T. Smollet, 1758); _On the subject of cold bathing, almost the only thing in which we can agree with him is, that it is little understood_ (W. Buchan, 1787).

Answer (score 3):

We would commonly use **poorly understood**, however **not well understood** would read well to a native speaker.

They do have slightly different meanings; **poorly understood** could also mean **incorrectly understood**, which is not the same. **Not well understood** can imply that what is understood is correct, but that it is only a subset of the facts, whereas **poorly understood** could imply, like **incorrectly understood** that the facts are interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, in my context, what you mean by "incorrectly understood" is not a meaningful concept; I meant, that mankind has not understood the laws yet; so there is no possibility to say if this is incorrect. 

So, "ill" is definitely not a choice?

Comment: "**Not well understood** can also mean ***not broadly understood*** or **not understood by many** *(people)*, so "ill" would not fit this meaning, "ill" is the same as *misunderstood* in this case.

Comment: well, thank you, I'll have to accept this, obviousy my Sprachgefühl (seems to be an english expression?) misguided me here

Comment: unfortunately I had to change the accepted answer, since what J.R. wrote is more exactly what I was asking for... Maybe it's the guilt of all these non-native scientists like me, that they did not like a non-idiomatic expression ;)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the great answer by Brian, you could consider using

> the laws are **difficult** to understand.

When something is well-understood, it means it is easy (not difficult) to understand. And when something is difficult to understand, people don't understand them well.

Using an adjective such as "[complex](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/complex)" or "[complicated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/complicated#complicated__2)" could be considered if the cause of them not being understood well is they are consisting of many different and connected parts or elements as follows:

> The laws are complex / complicated to understand.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks. But actually I didn't mean special people, but mankind as a whole. So the statement is supposed to be much more objective than "difficult" or "complex" would convey, right?

Comment: okay, thank you; I thought, that there has to be an equally well-sounding (probably I misjudged it and to call it idiomatic would be more well-understood :)) opposite. Apparently there isn't

Comment: @Ilja My pleasure. I think the most important thing is how you get the meaning across in a more concise, simple and accurate way. It all depends on the context and I'd like to advise you to search the internet for similar expressions with your own context. Without context, it is not easy to tell which one is better. I just suggested my ideas. :-)